# Sending a large string via NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to send large string from device to device with NFC. I understand that is possible in specs? But how to do it?

At the moment I have this kind of solution

```
    NdefRecord data = NdefRecord.createExternal("A", "ROW2", selected.substring(0, 4000).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{
            data
    });

    Log.d(TAG, msg.getByteArrayLength() + " Byte array");



    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(msg, this, this);
```

I try to send string from 0 to 4000 but it don't work.

Comment: Just as a note `setNdefPushMessage` is now deprecated, so not really a sustainable solution. It was removed because it was unreliable and when I tried to beam a smaller file than your string using the builtin beam software it never succeeded, so I can see why they removed it.

Comment: Thanks for info, what is the correct method?

Comment: Google were hinting that they would replace it with an easy to use method using wifi/bluetooth (though you could do that now yourself with more work) but if you still want to use NFC the only non deprecated method is to use Host Card Emulation on the sending device to pretend to be a NFC Card